# adding and subtracting to the array range

Tags: javascript, arrays, range

Hey I have a question about this piece of code that I have:

```
var levelsRange = arrayeventslevel[0] + " through " +  arrayeventslevel[arrayeventslevel.length-1]; ; 
$("#existorders").html(
  "There are currently: " + arrayeventslength.length + 
  " events on " + dayoftheweek + 
  "<br/>" + " with order levels: " + levelsRange + 
  "<br />" + "You can move new event to levels ranging between: " + newLevelsRange
);
```

currently `levelsRange` outputs for example 1 through 6 range. If that is the case,
I need another variable `newLevelsRange` that should say 0 through 7 based on initial variable range.
However, if `levelsRange`says 0 through 6, new variable should say 0 through 7 NOT -1 through 7

I am having trouble adding subtracting properly from initial variable information. Can someone please assist.

Comment: Use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to not go below zero. Otherwise without that, it's a simple numeric comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newLevelsRange=(arrayeventslevel[0]||1)-1 + " through " +  (arrayeventslevel[arrayeventslevel.length-1]-1);
```

Simply check if the first element is zero, if so, take 1...

Comment: I just tried to replace what I have with what you gave me and I got NaN for this variable

Comment: @Jonasw: Maybe you should test your solution before asking the OP to check it with a jsfiddle. Just sayin'...

Comment: I know... operator precedence can be a killer.

Comment: Though not strictly necessary, I'd probably put the first part in parens too, just for clarity. `((arrayeventslevel[0]||1)-1)` But your code does look correct now, so thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this

```
 if(arrayeventslevel[0] != 0){
                            arrayeventslevel[0] = arrayeventslevel[0] - 1;
                        arrayeventslevel.length  =arrayeventslevel.length + 1;
                     }

                     var newLevelRange = arrayeventslevel[0] + " through " +  arrayeventslevel.length;
```

not sure how to use Math.max

Comment: overriding an arrays length property is the worst you can do. just sayin

Comment: @Jonasw: That doesn't override it but sets it to a value, which if different from the original, will either truncate or extend the array. Whether or not it's a good idea here depends on how the array is to be used after that point. I will say though that on the surface, this seems like an odd use of an Array. Who knows though, may make sense.

Comment: @coder: `var levelsRange = Math.max(0, arrayeventslevel[0] - 1) + " through " +  (arrayeventslevel[arrayeventslevel.length-1] + 1);` The `Math.max` part will give you the larger of `0` and `arrayeventslevel[0] - 1`, so if the latter falls below `0`, you'll get `0`.